# How to use different Origin accounts for different Windows users

Tags: origin, windows

Similar to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40761/how-do-you-force-steam-to-use-a-different-account-for-each-windows-user-account) I want to force Origin to log in with different accounts when logging in with different Windows users.

My wife and I share the same gaming PC, each having an own Windows user and an own Origin account. Unfortunately Origin remembers its settings globally, which means that it's automatically logging in with my wife's account when I log in with my Windows account and she was using Origin before.

Is there a way to have Origin's auto-login working for both of us on the same machine?

Comment: Well the first time you ever logged into Origin was there "Remember Me" check box anywhere that you could un-check? That's probably what's causing the problem.

Comment: Sure, that would prevent Origin from logging in automatically on startup. But that's what I want actually, because it's pretty convenient... but for both of us.

Comment: Well if you are both on the same PC then Origin will always try to log the last person who was on. Since you each have your own account on Windows then I don't know why it would be doing this. Perhaps you or your wife logged onto Origin when you were on her account or vice versa? because it's either that or possibly a bug with Origin.