# How to configure steam on a multiuser system?

Tags: steam

I have installed Steam on my laptop. I frequently lend this laptop to my friend. He even has his own account on the machine (which is running Windows 7 btw).

Now my problem is: If one of us tells Steam to Autologin and save the password this seems to get saved on the computer instead of the useraccount. So after I've lend my laptop to my friend, where he logs in with his account and signs in with steam, while saving his password, if I log into my account and start steam I get automatically logged into his account and vice versa. Is there any way to restrict this behavior to only save the password for the useraccount Steam got started in the first place?

Comment: You can either use command-line arguments to specify in a startup command, or create seperate installations of Steam per user. [It's been already answered. Lemmie find the link.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40761/how-do-you-force-steam-to-use-a-different-account-for-each-windows-user-account)