# Can I make steam remember the password for both of my steam accounts?

Tags: steam

I followed the instructions from [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/345617/73976) to an absolute t there and it works great. Only thing is that no matter what I try, whenever I double click on the icon for my second account it asks me to enter the password. Whether I have the "Remember my Password" box ticked or not on either account... no matter what combination I use... my PC will only remember 1 account's password (even, if as I said, the box is ticked) Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use a password manager instead?

Comment: Hi James, I hope you can find a suitable answer there, as there seems to be no native option for Steam to remember more than one password.